# Two functions synchronously run in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, function, setinterval, synchronize

I wrote a script that simulates a crossfade of images and causes a change of text. This is the code now:

```
var teller = 0;
var html = new Array();
var link = new Array();
html[0] = "Some text";
link[0] = "link1.html";
html[1] = "Some other text";
link[1] = "link2.html";
function beeldwissel() {
    tekstwissel();
    var $actief = $('#overvloeier IMG.actief');
    if ( $actief.length == 0 ) $actief = $('#overvloeier IMG:last');
    var $next =  $actief.next().length ? $actief.next() : $('#overvloeier IMG:first');
    $actief.addClass('laatst-actief');
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('actief')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $actief.removeClass('actief laatst-actief');});
        }

$(function() {setInterval( "beeldwissel()", 5000 );}); // 5000 = pauze van 5 seconden

function tekstwissel() {
    teller++;
    if (teller >= html.length) {
        teller = 0;
    }   
    document.getElementById('tel').value = teller;
    document.getElementById('tekst').innerHTML = html[teller];
}

function doLink() {
    var tel = document.getElementById('tel').value;
    window.open(link[tel],'_blank');
}
```

If I change focus than the change of text and change of image is not synchronized anymore...

What do I have to change to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The two functions can't run at the same time without it being async. The best you can do is use two timeouts with a very little time set:

```
setTimeout(function() { /* code... */ },1);
setTimeout(function() { /* code... */ },1);
```

That way the two functions execute at the same time.

However, in your case, wouldn't it be simpler if you just used one function or made the first one call the other one:

```
function trigger() {
     // Do image fading here...
     // Text manipulation here...
}
```